# Error 401 api woocommerce al intentar hacer GET (Reactjs)

Tags: javascript, wordpress, reactjs, woocommerce, babel

Estoy realizando un proyecto con Reactjs, el cual consume datos de la api de wordpress y de Woocommerce. Los datos de Worpress los extrae correctamente pero los datos de Woocommerce me devuelven un error 401.

> {code: "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error", message: "La clave de cliente > no es válida.", data: {…}}
>   code: "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error"
>   data: {status: 401}
>   message: "La clave de cliente no es válida."
>   **proto**: Object

Lo primero que pensé fue en un error en las claves de cliente o la secreta pero son las correctas e creado otra nuevas por si estuvieran fallando pero sigue igual.

También quiero añadir que cuando trabajaba en local (localhost) todo funcionaba correctamente, pero como he cambiado a un servidor externo el cual tiene su respectivo wordpress y woocommerce.

```
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://www.xxxxxx.xxxxx.com/',
  consumerKey: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  consumerSecret: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  wpAPI: true,
  version: 'wc/v3',
  queryStringAuth: true
});

WooCommerce.getAsync('customers').then((result) => {
  let customers = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
  let WordApi = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users";

  fetch (WordApi, {mode:'cors'}) 
    .then (data => data.json ()) 
    .then (data => { 
     console.log(data);
     this.setState ({ 
       shopManager: data[0],
       cargado2: true
    }) 
  }) 

  this.setState({
    customers: customers,
  });
```